# dynamically load modules in Meteor node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to load multiple modules on the fly via chokidar (watchdog) using Meteor 1.6 beta, however after doing extensive research on the matter I just can't seem to get it to work.

From what I gather require by design will not take in anything other than static strings, i.e.

```
require("test/string/here")
```

Since if I try:

```
var path = "test/string/here"
require(path)
```

I just get Error: Cannot find module, even though the strings are identical.

Now the thing is I'm uncertain how to go on about this, am I really forced to either use import or static strings when using meteor or is there some workaround this?

```
watchdog(cmddir, (dir) => {
match = "." + regex_cmd.exec(dir);

match = dir;

loader.emit("loadcommand", match)


});

loader.on('loadcommand', (file) => {
require(file);
});
```

Comment: I used react-loadable and dynamic imports worked like a charm!

Comment: Are these modules regular npm modules, or your own scripts (ie not in /imports)? If the latter, you need to give it an absolute path or it won't work

Comment: Or at least a sufficient relative path. Does `/test/string/here` work?

Comment: @Mikkel my own scripts.

Comment: @Dom Well I suppose to that could technically work, I might try that out.

Comment: @Michel Floyd Was this via meteor's package or npm?

Answer (score 0):

There is something intrinsically weird in what you describe.

`chokidar` is used to watch actual files and folders.

But Meteor compiles and bundles your code, resulting in an app folder after build that is totally different from your project structure.

Although Meteor now supports dynamic imports, the mechanism is internal to Meteor and does not rely on your actual project files, but on Meteor built ones.

If you want to dynamically `require` files like in Node, including with dynamically generated module path, you should avoid `import` and `require` statements, which are automatically replaced by Meteor built-in import mechanism. Instead you would have to make up your own loading function, taking care of the fact that your app built folder is different from your project folder.

That may work for example if your server is watching files and/or folders in a static location, different from where your app will be running.

In the end, I feel this is a sort of XY problem: you have not described your objective in the first place, and the above issue is trying to solve a weird solution that does not seem to fit how Meteor works, hence which may not be the most appropriate solution for your implicit objective.

Comment: Well essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is loading in separate commands (for the program to trigger via events) into meteor in real time, which is why I use chokidar to watch a specific folder and it's sub-folders.

Comment: If by "real time" you mean not available at app build time, then it is out of scope of Meteor, and you have to make up your own loading function, as stated above.

Comment: Sorry for asking about this, but I'm wondering if you got any links/books that could help when it comes to implementing your own loading function.

Comment: If you want to load the script Client side, look for "dynamically load JavaScript". The idea is to create a `<script>` tag and to insert it into the DOM. If you want to execute it Server side, you have plenty options to read the content of a file and evaluate it, or launch a bash command that will use `node` to execute the script. You should be able to find plenty resources for all these options, including here on SO.

Comment: BTW be very careful about who can provide the script and have it executed, since it is basically code injection, a giant open door for attacks.

Answer (score 0):

@Sashko does a great job of explaining Meteor's dynamic imports [here](https://blog.meteor.com/dynamic-imports-in-meteor-1-5-c6130419c3cd). There are also [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/dynamic-import.html)

A dynamic import is a *function* that returns a *promise* instead of just importing statically at build time. Example:

```
import('./component').then((MyComponent) => {
  render(MyComponent);
});
```

The promise runs once the module has been loaded. If you try to load the module repeatedly then it only gets loaded once and is immediately available on subsequent requests.

afaict you can use a variable for the string to import.